# Present top 3 distribution of values in iris

Tags: r

I want to present the top 3 most common values of sepal.length in each species in order to present it as a bar diagram.

```
library(Publish)

iris$Sepal.Length<-as.character(iris$Sepal.Length)
UnivariateTable(Species~Sepal.Length, data=iris)



Variable Level setosa (n=50) versicolor (n=50) virginica (n=50) Total (n=150) p-value

1  Sepal.Length   4.3       1 (2.0)           0 (0.0)          0 (0.0)       1 (0.7)        
2                 4.4       3 (6.0)           0 (0.0)          0 (0.0)       3 (2.0)        
3                 4.5       1 (2.0)           0 (0.0)          0 (0.0)       1 (0.7)        
4                 4.6       4 (8.0)           0 (0.0)          0 (0.0)       4 (2.7)        
5                 4.7       2 (4.0)           0 (0.0)          0 (0.0)       2 (1.3)        
6                 4.8      5 (10.0)           0 (0.0)          0 (0.0)       5 (3.3)        
7                 4.9       4 (8.0)           1 (2.0)          1 (2.0)       6 (4.0)        
8                   5      8 (16.0)           2 (4.0)          0 (0.0)      10 (6.7)        
9                 5.1      8 (16.0)           1 (2.0)          0 (0.0)       9 (6.0)        
10                5.2       3 (6.0)           1 (2.0)          0 (0.0)       4 (2.7)        
11                5.3       1 (2.0)           0 (0.0)          0 (0.0)       1 (0.7)        
12                5.4      5 (10.0)           1 (2.0)          0 (0.0)       6 (4.0)        
13                5.5       2 (4.0)          5 (10.0)          0 (0.0)       7 (4.7)        
14                5.6       0 (0.0)          5 (10.0)          1 (2.0)       6 (4.0)        
15                5.7       2 (4.0)          5 (10.0)          1 (2.0)       8 (5.3)        
16                5.8       1 (2.0)           3 (6.0)          3 (6.0)       7 (4.7)        
17                5.9       0 (0.0)           2 (4.0)          1 (2.0)       3 (2.0)        
18                  6       0 (0.0)           4 (8.0)          2 (4.0)       6 (4.0)        
19                6.1       0 (0.0)           4 (8.0)          2 (4.0)       6 (4.0)        
20                6.2       0 (0.0)           2 (4.0)          2 (4.0)       4 (2.7)        
21                6.3       0 (0.0)           3 (6.0)         6 (12.0)       9 (6.0)        
22                6.4       0 (0.0)           2 (4.0)         5 (10.0)       7 (4.7)        
23                6.5       0 (0.0)           1 (2.0)          4 (8.0)       5 (3.3)        
24                6.6       0 (0.0)           2 (4.0)          0 (0.0)       2 (1.3)        
25                6.7       0 (0.0)           3 (6.0)         5 (10.0)       8 (5.3)        
26                6.8       0 (0.0)           1 (2.0)          2 (4.0)       3 (2.0)        
27                6.9       0 (0.0)           1 (2.0)          3 (6.0)       4 (2.7)        
28                  7       0 (0.0)           1 (2.0)          0 (0.0)       1 (0.7)        
29                7.1       0 (0.0)           0 (0.0)          1 (2.0)       1 (0.7)        
30                7.2       0 (0.0)           0 (0.0)          3 (6.0)       3 (2.0)        
31                7.3       0 (0.0)           0 (0.0)          1 (2.0)       1 (0.7)        
32                7.4       0 (0.0)           0 (0.0)          1 (2.0)       1 (0.7)        
33                7.6       0 (0.0)           0 (0.0)          1 (2.0)       1 (0.7)        
34                7.7       0 (0.0)           0 (0.0)          4 (8.0)       4 (2.7)        
35                7.9       0 (0.0)           0 (0.0)          1 (2.0)       1 (0.7) < 1e-04
```

Now I want to present the top 3 most common length in each species, that is:

```
Setosa:         4.8(10%), 5(16%), 5.1(16%), Others(58%)
Versicolor:     5.5(10%), 5.6(10%), 5.7(10%), Others (70%)
Virginica:      6.3(12%), 6.4(10%), 6.7(10%), Others(68%)
```

And finally I want to present it in a bar diagram.

Anyone eager to help?

Best H

Comment: Maybe something like `lapply(split(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species), function(i) sort(prop.table(table(i)), decreasing = TRUE)[1:3])`

Comment: Thank I want to point out that sepal.length should be character as the dataset I really use contains categorical data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, there is bound to be a simpler and better way though!

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

df <- 
  iris %>% 
  mutate(Sepal.Length = as.character(Sepal.Length, droplevels = TRUE)) %>% 
  group_by(Species, Sepal.Length) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n)) %>% 
  arrange(Species, desc(freq)) %>% 
  mutate(rank = row_number(desc(freq)),
         g = case_when(rank > 3L ~ 4L,
                       TRUE ~ rank)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(Species, g) %>% 
  mutate(Sepal.Length = case_when(g == 4L ~ "Others",
                                  TRUE ~ Sepal.Length)) %>% 
  summarise(freq = sum(freq),
            Sepal.Length = unique(Sepal.Length))
  
  
ggplot(df, aes(factor(g), freq, fill = Species))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.75), width = 0.7) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Sepal.Length), position = position_dodge(width = 0.75), vjust = -0.2)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:4, labels = c("1st", "2nd",  "3rd", "Others"))+
  labs(x = "Most frequent sepal lengths")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will get you started :

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  count(Species, Sepal.Length, sort = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(n = n/sum(n) * 100) %>%
  slice(1:3)

#  Species    Sepal.Length     n
#  <fct>      <chr>        <dbl>
#1 setosa     5               16
#2 setosa     5.1             16
#3 setosa     4.8             10
#4 versicolor 5.5             10
#5 versicolor 5.6             10
#6 versicolor 5.7             10
#7 virginica  6.3             12
#8 virginica  6.4             10
#9 virginica  6.7             10
```